# Renjin: How to clear context?

Tags: renjin

As I understand, Renjin context contains variables with their values.

Suppose, I invoked this once:

```
engine.eval("df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=(1:10)+rnorm(n=10))");
engine.eval("print(df)");
engine.eval("print(lm(y ~ x, df))");
```

How can I clear context so that invoking `engine.eval("print(df)");` produces exception about unknown variable after clearing context?

I want to eval different calculations without mixing context and recreating engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "context" you mean is I think the R global environment. Each instance of RenjinScriptEngine has its own, independent global environment.

You can inspect, modify, and clear the values set it in the global environment using R base functions, like so:

```
engine.eval("print(ls())");  // print all symbols in the global environment
engine.eval("rm(ls())");     // remove all symbols in the global environment 
                             // (that don't start with a "." )

engine.eval("rm(ls(all.names=TRUE))"); // remove everything
```

You can also use the javax.script API to do the same:

```
engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE).clear();
```

Depending on your use case, clearing the global environment may be sufficient, but keep in mind that a RenjinScriptEngine contains additional state.

If you load packages and/or their namespaces via `library()`, `require()` or `mypackage::fun()`, that will affect the internal state of the RenjinScriptEngine.

Other things that affect the Session-level (RenjinScriptEngine) state:

- Global options set via `options()`
- Random number generator state and seed
- Internal state of third-party packages
- Open files and other connections